# How is it possible to use the tab key to navigate between different child components in the same page with Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, accessibility

For accessibility reasons, all components but be navigable with the tab key. I have two components on a login page but the tab won't take the focus from the component above to the one below.

```
    <div class="content">
        <login-form
            [formBuilder]="fb"
            [submitting]="loginPageState.submitting"
        ></login-form>

        <div
            *ngIf="pageData.appSettings"
            class="login-page__link"
            [innerHtml]="pageData.appSettings.login_page_link | safe: 'html'"
        ></div>

        <login-identity
            (identity)="onIdentity($event)">
        </login-identity>
    </div>
```

Comment: If your component does not render to a HTML component that has [activation behaviour](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#activation) and can receive focus as-is, you probably are also missing keyboard handlers and ARIA roles. For example, a `<button>` already can receive focus, and fires a `click` event even when activated by the enter key. If you insist on using an entirely custom element, you’d need `<span class="button" role="button" onclick="…" onkeydown="…">`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add tabindex attribute to your component :
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

For your component can use like this :

```
<login-identity
  tabindex=3
  (identity)="onIdentity($event)">
</login-identity>
```

Or like :
in your component ts file :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'login-identity',
  ...
  host: {
    'tabindex': 3
  },
})
export class LoginIdentityComponent
```

Comment: This didn't work but using tabindex in the template of the actual child components did do the job. Thank you!

Comment: Using tabindex > 0 is highly discouraged, because you will mess with the tab order which is near to impossible to control in a component-based system. Use `tabindex="0"` to let the browser determine the right order. It’s a warning in the doc you linked (:

Comment: And if you make a non-standard element keyboard focusable with `tabindex`, while that seems to fix your initial problem by allowing the keyboard user to TAB to it, it will not help the screen reader user.  You will need a `role` and keyboard event handlers as @Andy said in his comment in the OP.